# How can I solve to run my python code run localy?

Tags: python, server, localhost, local

I already install python 3.7  version. and when I run in command then its works great. But when I try to run  http.server 8000 and then browse url then just display my index.py code not a run like web page.

Any idea for this.

I did change in httpd.cong file
1.

```
AddHandler cgi-script .py
ScriptInterpreterSource Registry-Strict
```

2. add

```
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.pl index.cgi index.asp index.shtml index.html index.htm \
                   default.php default.pl default.cgi default.asp default.shtml default.html default.htm \
                   home.php home.pl home.cgi home.asp home.shtml home.html home.htm index.py
</IfModule>
```

also please check my code

```
#!C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe

print('sarvesh')

#print(mycursor.rowcount, "record inserted.")
```

so please let me know.

See here My output
[image]

Comment: Does the index.py contain html code?

Comment: no only that above code. thats it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to put in cgi-bin folder?
Could you test to make sure your installation is all right?
Are you using any amp? ( xampp, wamp)

Comment: what can I put in cgi-bi?  Yes I  installation all right. I am using xampp.

Comment: hello, where is this CGI-bin folder?

Comment: C:\wamp64\cgi-bin or C:\xampp\cgi-bin. You can find the exact location in your httpd.conf.

Comment: Put your index.py file inside this folder.

Comment: It looks like your installation is not good, try to use an amp. http://www.wampserver.com/en/. Here's a great tutorial for installing a webserver on windows http://duspviz.mit.edu/tutorials/localhost-servers/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Create a folder called test.
open a command ("cmd.exe") in windows and enter the folder you created. ex "*cd c:\test*".
Create a cgi-bin folder. ex "*mkdir cgi-bin*"
run python embedded server. "*python3 -m http.server --cgi*"
Put your code in the cgi-bin folder.
Access from the browser http://127.0.0.1:8000/cgi-bin/index.py